# CSS element.style, where's it coming from and how do I turn it off?

Tags: css, video-streaming, element

I installed S3 Video Plugin for Wordpress -  it works beautifully except that it or my theme is applying padding-top % element.style and I can't alter the player size without it screwing up.  This copied from firebug:

```
element.style {
    padding-top: 59.375%;
}
.fluid-width-video-wrapper {
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.fluid-width-video-wrapper {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    content: "";
    height: 10px;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Firebug these days (seems that plenty (I'd hesitate to use most, but suspect it is most) people have moved to Chrome's Web Inspector). In Chrome's Web Inspector you can easily see where things are from, so try there instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is some JavaScript from the Player so the CSS gets added.
Write in your CSS-Rules `!important` to the part which should be definitely executed.

Comment: Where that would indeed overwrite the style, it's not very good advice to advocate it. Only if it's a last resort.

Answer (score 5):

Element style is, unsurprisingly, style on the element itself, such as

```
<div style="padding-top: 59.375%;"></div>
```

It will take precedence over any other styles you specify in CSS, unless you use `!important`

Comment: so if I add to the div:
 
    padding-top: 0px; !important

Will it override this style?

Comment: Worked a charm!  Thanks!

Comment: No problem!  Also, like @Kyle Sevenoaks points out, you should try to use `!important` when all other options have run out.  But if you have no control over the code that sets the element style, it may be your only choice.  Last minor point, the semicolon comes after !important, ie `padding-top: 0px !important;`

Answer (score 0):

`Element.style` is propably set by plugin you're using by one of its Javascript functions or something like that. It can be turned off by removing line where script is altering element's default CSS styles.